# How to get localization code from Locale?

Tags: swift, localization, internationalization, locale, foundation

Is there a way to get the localization code (language with region) from a `Locale` instance? Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
let locale = Locale(identifier: "en_CA")
locale.languageCode // en
locale.regionCode // CA
locale.identifier // en_CA
```

I'm trying to avoid manually constructing the localization because both language and region codes are optional which adds complexities. How do I properly get the localization `en-CA`?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you want to get the locale identifier in the form en-CA instead of en_CA, is that it?

Comment: en-CA is the localization, but en_CA is the locale identifier. the localization is made of the language and region.

Comment: Can't you just replace the _ with - in an extension? 
Like : `extension Locale
{
 var localisation:String
 {
  return identifier.replacingOccurrences(of: "_", with: "-")
 }
}` What you think about that?

Comment: That's what I've been thinking so far, but I was hoping for a native way to do that because that's assuming that all locale identifiers consistently translate that way.